# Entity Framework core seed without asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I currently starting a project that it can growth a lot. To create a good application that I can easily maintain, I'm trying to implement a complex architecture to separate Business/Logic/View...

So my model are in a different project ( .net core library ).

My problem is, that I did not found how to create a Seed to add some data in my database tables without using Startup.cs...

Somebody already implement seed method when database is update ?

Comment: Use EF-core if you like to live dangerously. The "RTM" version is practically a beta.

Comment: yep, after some research I read that some basic functionnalities are not yet implemented. I work with EFCore because i need to target all OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeding is done when you Update your database using migrations. So the questions you have to answer are.

- Are you using Code First Migrations?
- How are you intending to run them?

When you work out how you intend to run migrations, that will be the same method you use to "seed".

Comment: Yes I am using Code First. And I execute the migration using console. I already created Seed method on EF6 that they be applied on update, but with EF core, I don't find any seed method to do it on update